# Fetch random images from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, image, random

I am trying to fetch random images from database on external page the script works fine but it fetches id user id name only image and I only want to fetch images with active link

It's like most of the wallpapers site where they display thumbnail on there home page or somewhere randomly and when user click on wallpapers it redirect to wallpapers(or large image)

Here is my code

```
<?php

$connect= mysql_connect('localhost','root',' ');
if($connect) {
    mysql_select_db ('wall_paper',$connect);

    $query= ("SELECT * FROM wallpapers ORDER BY Rand() LIMIT 5");
    $result= mysql_query($query);

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
        echo "<tr><td>$row[0] </td><td>$row[1]</td><td>$row[2]</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "cant connet to the database";
}
?>
```

The database from I'm fetching images from:

[Database Image](http://i50.tinypic.com/mm4bap.jpg)

Comment: Can you give us the schema of your table ?

Comment: So ... `WHERE active=1`?

Comment: if i change this to 0 it will deactivate wallpaper

Comment: Since you are displaying only id,userid,name only. what else do u want?

Comment: i want to display thumb from the hash

Comment: What are you storing in hash?

Comment: any other columns exist in the table?

Comment: can you give you database schema.. we need more details.

Answer (score 0):

To display image you need know image file path. In your DB you have only image parameters not path to file. If you can create path to file you can put it to result output:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)){
    $sPath = '/path_to_dir_with_images/'. $row[0] . '.jpg'; // something like this
    echo "<tr><td>{$sPath}</td></tr>";
}
```